# Which cable connection will result in a greater loss of power?

Tags: power, cables, loss

I know that running a power cable (the cable is carrying 5V DC, I plug in an AC to DC converter to the mains) that is, for example, 50m will cause losses in the power output. So if you measure at the source it will be 5V but when you measure at the end it might be 4.3V.

However, if I connect a mains extension cable that is 50m (the cable is carrying 230V AC) and then plugs in my AC to DC supply (this DC power cable is only 5cm) to my mains extension cable. Now I measure the output of the AC to DC power cable (at the end of the 5cm power cable) will I still get 5V or will the mains extension cable incur losses along the 50m and thus reduce the output of the AC to DC power supply from 5V to 4.3V?

Which is better Scenario 1 or 2, in order to minimize losses?

The AC mains extension is coming straight from the house's wall socket. There is no AC converter. just a three-pin plug plugged into the wall socket.

[image]

***Please don't ask to go and buy a 50m AC extension cable and test it. This question is asking about the principle of running an AC extension or a DC extension in order to reduce power losses. What if the cable is 5km long....?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run the higher voltage in the long cable. Higher voltage results to less current drawn for the same load.

Another reason is that the AC/DC converters usually have no problems providing stable 5 V even if the input drop a few volts. Some even work at a range from 100 V to 230 V, to be usable in ~110 V system.

Answer (score 2):

The losses are proportional to the current flowing in the wire, due to wire resistance.

Let's assume the load draws 5W, which will be 1A at 5V. Even if we assume that the power supply is ideal, and converts mains to 5W with 100% efficiency, it will draw only 5W.

Now as mains is 230VAC in your example, 5W is only 22mA. So because the current is so much smaller, there is less voltage drop over the wire. There is still enough voltage for the power supply to generate stable 5V locally.

Comment: I added a picture to illustrate what I am on about. Can you inform me what should the question marks in the picture should then be? For now, I assume there's no load because I want to see if there are losses in the cable and how much. I know there will be drop in scenario 1 due to cable losses but what about scenario 2?

Comment: Scenario 1 is wrong. If there is no load, there is no current in the wires, and thus there is no losses so there can be no voltage drop either. In scenario 2, there would be insignificant voltage drop from 230VAC and the power supply would happily provide stable 5V, unless the no-load voltage is 4.3V. What power supply it is?

Comment: https://www.meanwelldirect.co.uk/products/15w-single-output-encapsulated-type-power-supply/

Answer (score 1):

Any regulated switching converter, whether AC or DC in and/or out will maintain the voltage at its output and compensate for voltage droop at its input by drawing more current and thus more power at its input. You still incur power losses in the long cable, but the output voltage of the converter is controlled. For lowest power loss, have the long cable o the side with the least current (highest voltage). For lowest droop at the output do not have the long cable on the output.

Your question is equating voltage drop with cable losses. Not the same thing.

Comment: There is no AC converter. The AC extension just plugs straight into the wall socket, then runs that power through the 50m cable. So I am basically extending the wall socket and then plugging my AC to DC converter at the end of the AC 50m extension cable.

Comment: What I meant was any combination of AC and DC on input and output. ac-dc, dc-dc, dc-ac, ac-ac.

Comment: I added a picture to illustrate what I am on about. Can you inform me what should the question marks in the picture should then be?

Comment: @Joey You can't know without knowing the current and resistance. But since a switching converter and power in =  power out, you do know that the current on the 220V side will be lower than the 5V side. Lower current means lower voltage drop.